# Dart Sass failed with this error: Undefined variable. SASS

Tags: dart, sass, css-variables, codekit

I don't understand what this compile error is describing because I do define the SASS variable:

> Dart Sass failed with this error: Undefined variable.
> ╷
> 64 │     color: $sc-blue-light;
> │            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ╵
> _partials/navigation/_search.scss 64:12  @use
> style.scss 65:1                          root stylesheet

**_utilities.scss**

```
$sc-blue-light: #5BC2E7;
```

**_search.scss**

```
.search {
color: $sc-blue-light;
}
```

**_style.scss (the main stylesheet)**

```
@use '_partials/base/_utilities';
@use '_partials/navigation/_search';
```

The utilities are being loaded first, which is what I've read in other answers but it's not applying here. The file paths are correct.

All my other styles compile okay. It's just when I started using variables that this error comes up.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Add `@use` rule at top of the file in `_search.scss` too.

With namespace

```
@use '_partials/base/_utilities';

.search {
 color: utilities.$sc-blue-light;
}
```

or without namespace

```
@use '_partials/base/_utilities' as *;

.search {
 color: $sc-blue-light;
}
```

Quote from official sass

> Members (variables, functions, and mixins) loaded with @use are only
> visible in the stylesheet that loads them. Other stylesheets will need
> to write their own @use rules if they also want to access them.

and

> The simplest @use rule is written @use "", which loads the module
> at the given URL. Any styles loaded this way will be included exactly
> once in the compiled CSS output, no matter how many times those styles
> are loaded.

Read about [sass @use members](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#loading-members)
Read about [sass @use namespace](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace)

Comment: Thanks so much @Sameer! It was a namespace issue. That concept didn't register with me in the documentations. I created a namespace and made sure I called it in the style, and it worked! Your explanation made my understanding more clear, thank you.